# Comparing two conditions in short hand notation in if condition

Tags: ruby

Is there a shorthand way to write these two logical conditions?

```
if array[index] > array[index - 1] && array[index] > array[index + 1]
```

Into something like:

```
if array[index - 1] < array[index] > array[index + 1]
```

Comment: In python, yes, as far as I know in ruby, no.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently if you try to do `if array[index - 1] < array[index] > array[index + 1]`, you'll get an undefined method error, because you're using `>` in a FalseClass object, and such class doesn't implement nor `<` nor `>` methods. So, you'll have something like:

```
if true > array[index + 1]
  ...
end
# undefined method `>' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)
```

This will be for any "single" object in any side of the comparison trying to be accomplished.

```
array[index] > array[index - 1] && array[index] > array[index + 1]
```

This can be interpreted as a verification like if both or all objects are less than `array[index]`, so I guess you could use the [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F), which compares all the elements inside the array and returns true for the comparison being made inside the block, also if "all" elements satisfies it.

This would be an alternative in the case if you for some reason need to add more elements to the comparison, and don't care for the complex logic it'd create.

So, something like this could be written as:

```
p 'foo' if [array[index - 1], array[index + 1]].all? { |element| element < array[index] }

p 'foo' if array[index] > array[index - 1] && array[index] > array[index + 1]
```

Which eventually is more code, but if you need to add something to the expression, then it'd go just inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is max:

```
if [array[index - 1], array[index], array[index + 1]].max == array[index]
```

edit: or use the range selection added into the same method:

```
if array[index-1..index+1].max == array[index]
```

Comment: Speaking of 'shorthand' you can drop parens

`if array[index-1..index+1].max == array[index]`